# Automatically add links to class source files under a specified directory of another project in Visual Studio 2008 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I want to share some class *source files* between two projects in Visual Studio 2008. I can't create a project for the common parts and reference it (see my comment if you are curious to why).

I've managed to share some source files, but it could be a lot more neat. I've created a test solution called *Commonality*.

The Solution Explorer of the *Commonality* solution which contains project *One* and *Two*:

[image]

What I like:

- All class files under the *Common* folder of project *One* are automatically added to project *Two* by linking. It's mostly the same as if I would have chosen *Add / Existing Item... : Add As Link* on each new class source file.
- It's clear that these files have been linked in. The shortcut arrow symbol is marking each file icon.

What I do not like:

- The file and folder tree structure under Common of project *One* isn't included. It's all flat.
- The linked source files are shown under the project root of project *Two*. It would look much less cluttered if they were located under *Common* like in project *One*.

The file tree structure of the *Commonality* solution which contains project *One* and *Two*:

```
$ tree /F /A

Folder PATH listing for volume Cystem
Volume serial number is 0713370 1337:F6A4
C:.
|   Commonality.sln
|
+---One
|   |   One.cs
|   |   One.csproj
|   |
|   +---bin
|   |   \---Debug
|   |           One.vshost.exe
|   |           One.vshost.exe.manifest
|   |
|   +---Common
|   |   |   Common.cs
|   |   |   CommonTwo.cs
|   |   |
|   |   \---SubCommon
|   |           CommonThree.cs
|   |
|   +---obj
|   |   \---Debug
|   |       +---Refactor
|   |       \---TempPE
|   \---Properties
|           AssemblyInfo.cs
|
\---Two
    |   Two.cs
    |   Two.csproj
    |   Two.csproj.user
    |   Two.csproj~
    |
    +---bin
    |   \---Debug
    +---obj
    |   \---Debug
    |       +---Refactor
    |       \---TempPE
    \---Properties
            AssemblyInfo.cs
```

And the relevant part of project *Two*'s project file *Two.csproj*:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\One\Common\**\*.cs">
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="Two.cs" />
  <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How do I address what I do not like, while keeping what I like?

Comment: *Why can't I have the shared classes in its own assembly?* Project One and project Two reference different assemblies. Altough the assemblies are different a lot of their interface is shared. That's why I may re-use a class file. I'm unable to change the referenced assemblies as they are not created by me.

Comment: I don't get why, if you've got access to the common classes and both projects, you can't create a common project and reference it from Project One and Two?

Comment: Project One and Two reference two different versions of an external API which I can't change. The external API uses mostly the same namespaces, classes and methods for both versions. If I put all the common code in a separate project, then this project will have to reference either version 1 or 2 of the external API. This will drag a whole framework into the project and suddenly it won't be a "common" project any more, as it will drag a whole API of either version 1 or 2 into itself.

Comment: I still don't get why you can't use a common dll.  Can you explain what is in the common files that prevents you from creating a common dll (and what they reference)?

Comment: Maybe I can. I got told by a consultant that I couldn't. I'll look into this more. I'm quite new to .NET and C#. Thanks for shaking my belif system! (I'll accept as soon as I get it working, it'll take a couple of weeks though as I've got a work queue. Thank you for answering! (And Paolo too!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code.

Say you have two DLLs that expose the API you are using, one is newer.  They share the same namespace, and a lot of the same classes and methods.  In my example, here's the code for the two versions of the API:

**API V1.0:**

```
namespace API
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Call1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call1 in API1");
        }
    }
}
```

**API V2.0:**

```
namespace API
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Call1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call1 in API2");
        }

        public void Call2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call2 in API2");
        }

    }
}
```

You want to write a wrapper that uses the common stuff to start out on, so take what is common and create a common assembly, using an interface and an abstract base class.

**Interface:**

```
namespace ApiCommon
{
    public interface ICommon
    {
        void Call1();
    }
}
```

**Abstract class:**

```
namespace ApiCommon
{
    public abstract class CommonBase : ICommon
    {

        #region ICommon Members

        public void Call1()
        {
            Class1 common = new Class1();
            common.Call1();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now to extend your abstract class using either API V1.0 or V2.0, create a new project, and add a reference to your Common dll.

**Extended class:**

```
using ApiCommon;

namespace ConditionalTest
{
    public class MyApi : CommonBase
    {
        public void Call3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Call 3 MyApi");
        }
    }
}
```

Now the wiring to make it work.

Create two new build configurations in Configuration Manager, call them API1 and API2, and copy the settings off of Debug.

Edit your Common .csproj settings, and add these lines:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'API1|AnyCPU' ">
    <Reference Include="API1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\API1\bin\Debug\API1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'API2|AnyCPU' ">
    <Reference Include="API2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\API2\bin\Debug\API2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now when you build, depending on the Build Config option you choose (API1 or API2), it will link the Common.dll to the correct API, and you should be good to go.

To test it out, create a Console app with code like this:

```
namespace ConditionalTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyApi test = new MyApi();
            test.Call1();
            test.Call3();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the build you chose, it will either spit out:

```
Call1 in API1
Call 3 in MyApi
```

or

```
Call1 in API2
Call 3 in MyApi
```