# DLL Hell: old .dll file separated into two pieces?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a problem wherein a component I need to use for a project is configured to use an old DLL. Other components use the newer version of this DLL, and bindingRedirect seems to take care of most of these issues.

Here is the interesting issue that I am unsure how to solve (apologies for using abstarct names):
**Component X** tries to look for **type Y** in **DLL A**, because in the older version Y resided in A. However, in later versions A has been split into two DLL files, **A** and **B** (which contains a special branch of the things found in A). Type Y has been moved out of A and into B, but a lot of other important components are still residing in A.
Is there a way to make a binding so that X looks in B for these classes instead of A, or another way to solve this?
I lack access to any source code, but do have the old A .dll, although I would always want to use the new A .dll simultaneously.

I have tried using the codeBase property to link to old A, which went poorly, and QualifyAssembly, which also does not seem to do what I was searching for.

EDIT: As a workaround, I created a separate folder called LegacyDlls whuich is separate from my bin files (this part is very important) and placed the old version of Assembly A in there. Then I used a codebase tag like so:

```
<dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="A" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="AkeyGoesHere" />

            <codeBase version="2.1.0.0" href="LegacyDlls\A.dll" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

And I no longer get a TypeLoad exception, so I think this means progress!

Comment: If you control the code for your part, see my answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760558/automatically-add-links-to-class-source-files-under-a-specified-directory-of-ano/2768760#2768760

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you painted yourself into a corner.

There are ways of doing this by emitting code and adding the methods from B into A at runtime, but that would lead to serious maintenance issues in the long term so I wouldn't suggest it.

Either wait for the component to get a new version running on the new dlls or work without it.

Comment: I think you may very well be right. I tried to find alternate versions, such as [link]http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html[/link] to use in the interrim, but since I cannot modify where the faulty call is made, it seems I am still stcuk in a corner waiting for the paint to dry/a new version to be showed.